# How to get real coordinates in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, php, openlayers-3

In OpenLayers I use the ol.source.XYZ.

So I use a own URL with the Variables {x} {y} {z} and {a-z}. I want to render some pics with another Webserver.

But I don't understand what the Variables x y and z does tell me..

I need Coordinates in lat and lon. for example: 10.1234567 and 9.1234567. Google cant tell me, whether I can convert this? Or should I just use another OpenLayers solution?

OpenLayers give me the following values for example:

x=3, y=262144, z=19

Answer (score 0):

These coordinates are tile coordinates. `x` and `y` are the column and row in the tile grid, and `y` is the zoom level. If you need to know latitude and longitude of the tile corners, you can use

```
var extent = source.getTileGrid().getTileCoordExtent([z, x, y]);
```

This will give you the extent in the view projection. To convert to geographic coordinates, use

```
ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, map.getView().getProjection, 'EPSG:4326');
```